# OnTriggerEnter firing too late

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a sticky grenade by disabling its rigidbody upon collision, using `OnCollisionEnter()`. However, `OnCollisionEnter()` fires when there is clearly no collision happening, as you can see in this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EXD3.jpg. This causes my grenade to stick in the air. I suspect this is due to a lack of synchronization between physics loop & rendering loop. Also, my standard "non-sticky" grenade uses the same model & is working finely.

I already tried the following :

- Verify that there are no other colliders which could cause my grenade
  to "stick in the air"
- Use `OnTriggerEnter()`  instead. The result is a little better but the problem is that it is fired too late, only once the grenade is inside an obstacle or an enemy.
- Add rigidbody & continuous collision detection to all objects
- Tweak PhysicsManager.DefaultContactOffset from 0.01 to 0.001, as suggested by Eliasar
- Switch from "PCM" to "Legacy Contacts Generation"

None of these worked so I'm feeling a little desperate. Thanks in advance for your help !

Code I use to stick the grenade upon collision :

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c) {
   rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
   transform.parent = c.transform;
}
```

Comment: What type of collision detection have you tried on the [`RigidBody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html)?

Comment: I tried both continuous & continuous dynamic, without success

Answer (score 4):

## `PhysicsManager.DefaultContactOffset` might be set too high for your object scale

According to this [Unity forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/oncollisionenter-fires-too-early.473239/#post-3091253), your physics margin might be too high if your objects' scales are too small. `OnCollisionEnter` will fire during a Physics tick and may update your grenade's position a frame sooner than you're expecting. That would explain why it would stick outside the contact point, whereas `OnTriggerEnter` would process 1 frame later.

---

Unity post in text form

> Max_van_Hell, Jun 1, 2017
>
> oh god yeah Baby, I finally found the issue!
>
> Appearantly the PhysicsManager.DefaultContactOffset was too high for my scale. The Default contact Offset was about 0.02 and with virtual objects which are around 10cm it yields a HUGE error margin obviously.
>
> That never was a Problem for me, since in most graphics or game projects the scale of the objects is actually much larger so that such a contact Offset does not have a huge influence.
>
> However, since this is a HoloLens Project and I am working with virtual objects which are around 10cm - 100cm the contact offset is more sensible.
>
> Anyway, thank you much for your help!
>
> cheers,

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried tweaking PhysicsManager.DefaultContactOffset (from 0.01 to 0.001) and switching to "Legacy Contacts Generation" but that did not change anything unfortunately.